Integrate next-intl provided middleware with pre-existing middleware
I have an existing middleware that handles the auth.
Now i am trying to add the next-intl to my project. However i am having a hard time combining both of them.
I followed their tutorial and implemented everything as the doc says:
https://next-intl.dev/docs/getting-started/app-router/with-i18n-routing
I am using Next.JS 15 App Router with Src directory
Here is my existing middleware:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getSession } from "@/lib/auth/iron-session";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  const session = await getSession();
  const isLoggedIn = session.isLoggedIn;

  // Check if the user is logged in
  if (!isLoggedIn && pathname !== "/einloggen") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/einloggen", request.url));
  }
  if (isLoggedIn && pathname === "/einloggen") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
  }

  // Allow access to other pages
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  // Apply the middleware to all paths except for the ones we want to exclude (like _next and favicon.ico)
  matcher: ["/((?!_next|favicon.ico).*)"],
};


The conflict comes up because both the auth middleware and next-intl middleware have to process requests one after the other, which can lead to some path handling issues.
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { createMiddleware } from "next-intl/middleware";
import { getSession } from "@/lib/auth/iron-session";

// Initialize next-intl middleware
const nextIntlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "de"], // Add supported locales
  defaultLocale: "en",
});

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  // Run next-intl middleware for locale detection
  const intlResponse = nextIntlMiddleware(request);
  if (intlResponse) return intlResponse;

  // Run authentication logic
  const session = await getSession();
  const isLoggedIn = session?.isLoggedIn;

  if (!isLoggedIn && pathname !== "/einloggen") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/einloggen", request.url));
  }

  if (isLoggedIn && pathname === "/einloggen") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

// Middleware matcher configuration
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!_next|favicon.ico).*)" // Exclude _next and favicon.ico paths
  ],
};


I have tried this. it didn't work, if (intlResponse) return intlResponse; is always ending the middleware script, so the auth logic never runs.
